# LoginAction appends extra GET variable during redirection

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

Hello I am facing some issue with CakePHP v3.4.10 authentication. `"loginAction"` redirection appends an extra GET variable. For example if I visit my site on `www.example.com/admin/` CakePHP redirects to `www.example.com/admin/login?redirect=%2Fadmin%2F` instead of simply redirecting to www.example.com/admin/login. How can I get rid of the extra `redirect=%2Fadmin%2F` variable.

```
AppController.php
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');
    $this->loadComponent('Converter');
    $this->loadComponent('Cookie');
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'loginAction' => [
            'controller' => 'Admin',
            'action' => 'login'
        ]
    ]);
}

routes.php
$routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Home', 'action' => 'index', 'home']);
$routes->connect('/admin', ['controller' => 'Admin', 'action' => 'dashboard']);
$routes->connect('/admin/login', ['controller' => 'Admin', 'action' => 'login']);
```

Comment: Unrelated, but why not use the 'admin' `prefix`?

Comment: Let me try that Dave

Comment: It didn't work. Same problem

Comment: I wasn't suggesting it as a solution.  Just an oddity in your code.

Comment: Why get rid of it anyways? [**It has a purpose**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/9405).

Comment: Thanks @ndm. That is a useful link.